# Change spark.master to yarn in Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc, executor

I submit jobs to a spark cluster in Dataproc (with Hadoop Yarn). and I see that no matter the  properties that I set for spark.master and deployment-mode, when I go the Spark UI, in the Environment tab of the job it is always shown *local* for spark.master,  and the different stages of the job always uses the same executor id, even when there is room for more.

e.g.:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster mycluster --regionmyregion --class MyApp --properties 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class,,spark.master=yarn,spark.deploy-mode=cluster,spark.submit.deployMode=client,spark.executor.instances=2,spark.scheduler.mode=FIFO,spark.executor.cores=2,spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2'
```

Comment: You don't need to specify these properties, by default Dataproc Spark uses YARN, client mode and dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the job environment shows "local"? Is that meaningless @Dagang?

Comment: How did you open the Spark UI?

Comment: I set a private ssh tunnel as described here: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce 
or here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces

Then, through the browser I can access the Spark UI, and the Spark History Server: `http://mymasternode:4040 http://mymasternode:10200`

Comment: I had set
`.set("spark.master", "local")` in the code, and that had precedence over the properties sent while submitting.

Answer (score 2):

I had set
`.set("spark.master", "local")` in the code, and that had precedence over the properties sent while submitting.